# Error Building Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra

I tried to install the following gem:

http://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication

on Windows 7 running Ruby 1.9 from the One-Click Installer.

I got the following error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Joel>gem install sinatra-authentication
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sinatra-authentication:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby19/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yajl-ruby-
0.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yajl-ruby-0.7.5/ext/gem_mak
e.out
```

I looked everywehere online, tried to install earlier versions, and attempted a manual install without success (it gave me a `stack too deep` error).

I suspect there are problems with the `yajl-ruby` gem (http://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby), a dependency? (I think)

The logs in `gem_make.out` show:

```
C:/Ruby19/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Do you have any idea as to how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know ruby 1.9 had one-click installer. Can you provide a link to it?

Answer (score 3):

To compile C extensions, you need to install the devkit that comes with RubyInstaller. 
You will find a link to download it here: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads

Comment: Also a windows developer exploring ruby. I'd just finished recreating the devkit when I found this post. I want those hours back.  http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the gem installation depends on the `make` program being installed, which you do not have. You can use [GNU Make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm).

Comment: I actually installed that just after posting this, with no success.

Comment: Restarted my computer as well, and nope. Do I have to setup paths or something?

Comment: Fixed it using the env. variables.

Comment: I get another problem now. See below.

Comment: It's not just matter of not having `make`, he needs a whole C development environment for windows. If he installs the RubyInstaller Devkit he will get this.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem when trying to install rails on windows. After 45 minutes grumbling in front of the monitor, I stumbled across this rails installer, which got ruby and rails successfully installed on my machine!
http://railsinstaller.org/